# Change Homepage Title only in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, home-page, meta

> How can I change title of Homepage?

I have crated one cms page and set it as homepage. Now I need to change default title of magento for only my homepage.

All other pages will have default title but I need something different title for homepage only.

I added title in cms page but it didn't work.

I tried in config -> Design  settings. But it work for all pages. I need to modify title only for homepage specifically.
Let me know if any other solution is suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done from **Page Title** field as per following screen-shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below screen shots and paths.

**Cms => Pages => Search for your home page**

[image]
**System => Configuration => General => Web => Default Pages**

[image]

**Frontend:**

[image]

might be useful for you.